# How can I define ❌ as a bullet for a bullet list in Microsoft Word 2021?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I know how to get to the "Define New Bullet" > Symbol options here:

[image: screenshot]

But how can I search for (or paste) the specific character that I want?

Sometimes I want to use ❌ or ✅ or other unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approaches

1. Search for the Unicode online
2. Paste the symbol you want into MS Word and check the associated Font family

---

##### Method 1. Search for Unicode online

If you don't know the code or aren't sure exactly which symbol you want to use you can simply do an Internet search for the code. This is my prefered method as Google is very effective at finding the proper charaters and also doing `fuzzy` searches.

Examples:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+%E2%9D%8C
  **`"unicode ❌"`**
- https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode%20checkmarks
  **`"unicode checkmarks"`**

The example search **`"unicode checkmarks"`** will display `✓` (U+2713) from the [first result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark).  Clicking on that  [same result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark), a Wikipedia page, will provide the a table of additional check marks.  You can then simply type the associated character unicode (e.g. `U+2705` ✅) into the symbol tool.

[Wikipedia: Check Marks > Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark#Unicode)

| Code | Symbol | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U+237B | ⍻ | NOT CHECK MARK |
| **U+2705** | **✅** | **WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK** |
| U+2713 | ✓ | CHECK MARK |
| U+2714 | ✔ | HEAVY CHECK MARK |
| U+10102 |  | AEGEAN CHECK MARK |
| U+1D93F |  | SIGNWRITING MOVEMENT-WALLPLANE CHECK SMALL |
| U+1D940 |  | SIGNWRITING MOVEMENT-WALLPLANE CHECK MEDIUM |
| U+1D941 |  | SIGNWRITING MOVEMENT-WALLPLANE CHECK LARGE |
| U+1F5F8 |  | LIGHT CHECK MARK |
| U+1F5F9 |  | BALLOT BOX WITH BOLD CHECK |
| U+1FBB1 |  | INVERSE CHECK MARK |

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

##### Method 2. Paste the symbol in Word

You can alternatively paste the symbol you want to use into MS Word and then with the symbol highlighted, check the `Font Family`.  This may not be ideal if you don't know in advance exactly what you want to use.

Highlighting ❌ in MS Word I see that on my system it is part of the `Segoe UI Emoji` font family.

I can now select `Segoe UI Emoji` in the symbol font drop menu and scroll through it to find the ❌.

[image]
[image]

---

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Now I have another related question. I'd love your help if you have a moment. Thanks! https://superuser.com/questions/1763584/how-export-emojis-in-color-from-word-2021-to-pdf