# How export emojis in color from Word 2021 to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, export, microsoft-word-2016

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Open a new blank Word 2021 document.
2. Paste in text with characters like: ✅  ❌ (Segoe UI Emoji)
3. Export to PDF.
4. Notice that the color emojis that worked in Word are now black and white in the PDF.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @BlindSpots Acrobat Reader 2022.003.20310. I've also tried opening the PDF in Brave and Edge browsers, and the emojis lack color there too. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by export? Save as PDF? Print to PDF? Export to PDF?

Comment: With your help, I figured it out! If you post an answer, I'll accept it. Basically, I'd tried Export to PDF and Print to PDF but had not tried Save As PDF. When I tried Save As PDF just now, I noticed to the left of the Save button, Tools > Web Options > Browsers > Options > uncheck "Rely on CSS for font formatting". Then choose to save as a ".pdf" file. It worked! Thanks! @BlindSpots

Comment: @Ryan - You should submit what you did as an answer yourself

Comment: I'd rather give credit to @BlindSpots because I would not have figured it out otherwise.

Comment: @Ryan I can't take credit for that, even if it triggered more testing for you.   I was off PC so just getting clarification prior to investigating.  You did the legwork and deserve the credit.  Ty though!

Answer (score 1):

Prior to writing the question above, I'd tried "Export to PDF" and "Print to PDF" but had not tried "Save As PDF".

1. Choose to "Save As PDF".
2. To the left of the Save button, click: Tools > Web Options > Browsers > Options > uncheck "Rely on CSS for font formatting".
3. Choose to save as a ".pdf" file.

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I wasn't able to find a solution / fix on Office 2019 except from printing into PDF.

The fix given by @Ryan is not working on Office 2019.

The best solution I found was to use a more recent version of Office. No issues / configuration needed with Office 365 to keep the colors for emojis

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1237401)